# OnNewToken call two times?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

As per the documentationof onNewToken,

> Called when a new token for the default Firebase project is generated.This is invoked after app install when a token is first generated, and again if the token changes.

Q1. Does this mean, it be get called 2 times???

Q2. I wan to send updated token to the server. If answer of Q1 is yes, then how to check onNewToken is received due to token change so that I can send updated token to server?

Answer (score 2):

The token may change in below situation:

- The app deletes Instance ID.
- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstall/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

You can create your own class that extends from "FirebaseMessagingService" to send the updated token to server:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
    }

    /**
    * Called if InstanceID token is updated.
    */
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        //send updated token to server
    }
}
```

and you should register it in the manifest:

```
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: after The app deletes Instance ID, at what point does it go to the onNewToken()?

Comment: @Coder123 To add to that question, does onNewToken() ever get called in the background, or only when the app is foregrounded?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't know in advance that it'll be called exactly two times. For example, a user might never restore the app on a new device, so it might only be called once. Or a user might do it multiple times, and it'll be called more than two times.

As for determining what to do, usually the logic doesn't need to consider whether a token was freshly generated or updated, because in both cases that token is now what the server should be using, so you would send it to the server unconditionally.